# angularjs: copy&paste tab delimited text to textarea then convert to table

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an app in which users copy and paste tab delimited text. I want to take the  text and make into a table (each new column is a tab and each new row is a new line in the pasted text.

I have the following which builds a list for each new line in the pasted text, but how do I get an array from tab delimited text?

```
 <div ng-app>

   <textarea ng-model="items" ng-list="/\n/"></textarea>
   <table>
     <tbody>
       <tr ng-repeat="item in items">
         <td>
           {{item}}
         </td>
       </tr>
     </tbody>
   </table>

</div>
```

Since I can't paste tab delimited text here without it reformatting... To get tab delimited text copy and paste from Notepad or a spreadsheet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does this work for you? http://jsbin.com/bosamuhoti/1/edit

Here's a snippet:

Angular app

```
angular.module('myapp', [])
.controller('myCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope){
    $scope.items = [];
    $scope.table  = []; 

  $scope.$watch("items", (newValue, oldValue) => {

    for (var item of newValue) {
        $scope.table.push(item.split('\t'));
      }

  });
}]);
```

And the corresponding HTML

```
<textarea ng-model="items" ng-list="&#10;" ng-trim="false"></textarea>

   <table border="1">
     <tbody>

       <tr ng-repeat="item in table track by $index">
         <td ng-repeat="data in item track by $index">
           {{data}}
         </td>
       </tr>
     </tbody>
   </table>
```

Comment: can you provide a set of data that you're testing your solution with?

Comment: I edited my original post to include my test data (tab delimited, two lines)

Comment: ok, do you want your solution to work without additional angularjs code (i.e. controller?)

Comment: I've updated my answer... hopefully this is closer to what you want?

Comment: This works great.I tweaked it a bit for better use but thanks so much!